# C# Windows Service High CPU Usage with Foreach loop, how to Minimize the cpu usage?

Tags: c#

Im Still Newbie to Windows Service , this service will loop every 30 seconds and display data but the cpu usage keeps on increasing from 0% to 70% and never decreases. What im asking is how to minimize the cpu usage? i heard looping is the cause of high cpu usage , tried the lamda foreach but nothing changes

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Connect();
        WriteToFile("Service Starts at " + DateTime.Now);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 30000; 
        timer.Enabled = true;
        GetData();

    }

    private void onElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      GetData();
    }

     private void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
        ICollection<MachineInfo> lstmachineInfo 
        =manipulator.GetLogData(objZkeeper, 
        int.Parse(tbxMachineNumber.Text.Trim()));

            if (lstmachineInfo != null && lstmachineInfo.Count > 0)
            {
            var result = lstmachineInfo.ToList().Where(a => a.datetime 
                         >=DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1)).ToList();

              WriteToFile(result.Count + " records found......");

              foreach (var data in result)
               {
                  WriteToFile("MachineNumber: " + data.MachineNumber + " 
                  UserID : " + data.IndRegID +" Datetime : " + 
                  data.DateTimeRecord + " Status : " + data.InOut);

               }

            }
            else
            {
                WriteToFile("failed in connecting with device, reconnecting 
                 ....");
                objZkeeper = new ZkemClient(RaiseDeviceEvent);
                isDeviceConnected = objZkeeper.Connect_Net(IPAddress, Port);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Errorlogs(ex.ToString());
            Errorlogs("\n");
        }

    }
```

Comment: How much data are we talking?

Comment: If the work needs to be done then it needs to be done. You are not doing anything crazy intensive; plus you have not provided what `WriteToFile` does. How do you know forach is the culprit? So what if CPU is at 70%?

Comment: @ChaosPandion it only shows data that is 1minute ago . if today is 10:30:30 the data displayed are those who logins in 10:30:00

Comment: Something smells fishy here and we don't have the appropriate information. The only loop i can see just calls `WriteToFile`

Comment: @CodingYoshi WriteToFile is just a event log

Comment: Also writing a tone of data to the event log (if you are using the term correctly) is a little suspect by itself

Comment: lstmachine is a list ,then with results i insert linq queries which only displays data that has inserted 1minute ago then using foreach loop to display the data that has inserted 1minute ago

Comment: @TheGeneral i already tried writing only the displayed data yesterday but still not working

Comment: Anyway, if you want to know whats causing your high cpu and how to solve it, we cant help you, we don't have enough information. If you want to reduce your cpu usage (which is just hiding what i think is a design problem) do as the answer suggests and just use thread sleep

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks im using the Thread.Sleep and still observing the cpu usage  .as of now the cpu usage is at minimum state thanks

Comment: If GetData() takes more than 30 seconds you have a probem as the next call will be triggered while the previous one is still running.

Answer (score 2):

Add `Thread.Sleep(10);` to your foreach loop. This will cause the process to pause for 10 milliseconds every iteration, which is a lifetime for a CPU.